# refer to __file__ from imported module

Tags: python, module, program-entry-point

I have a main program main.py which imports a module lib.py

Is it possible to have a variable in lib.py which returns the name of the main program which called the script? I mean something which would return "lib.py" if lib.py is run directly and "main.py" if it is main.py which has been run and have called lib.py

Here is lib.py

```
import os
print(os.path.basename(__file__))
```

If I run lib.py, then the output is what I want, that is

> lib.py

Here is main.py

```
import lib
print(__file__)
```

The output is

> lib.py
> main.py

Is there a variable, that I can call from lib.py, containing the name of the main program?
I would like the output

> main.py
> main.py

Comment: `sys.argv[0]` ?

Comment: Yep! It works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [[Python.Docs]: sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) (**emphasis** is mine):

> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. **`argv[0]` is the script name** (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not). If the command was executed using the [-c](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-c) command line option to the interpreter, `argv[0]` is set to the string `'-c'`. If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter, `argv[0]` is the empty string.

Therefore, you should use `sys.argv[0]` (don't forget to `import sys` 1<sup>st</sup>).